# How can I repair my broken drawer runners?

Tags: drawer-construction, drawer

I have under-bed dresser drawers that use two under-drawer metal runners with ball bearings. However, all of the runners are broken or missing their ball bearings.

I've considered fixing the drawers to use side mounts but there's not enough space.

My goal is to replace them with these [Home Deopt 18 in. Slides](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Liberty-18-in-Soft-Close-Ball-Bearing-Full-Extension-Drawer-Slide-2-Pack-941805/205171291), one per drawer, placed on their side underneath the drawer.

I was also thinking of using [Lowes Richelieu 22.75-in Drawer Slides](http://www.lowes.com/pd_380988-93052-T9952G_0__?productId=50041758), one per drawer, upside down on the top of drawer to prevent the drawer from tipping when opened.

I am not sure if I also need rubber bumpers or felt in front since these are self-closing.

Has anyone done anything like this?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't recommend trying to improvise with the wrong style of slide, because it will take longer, is likely to be more frustrating, and may not work as well in the end. That said, you do have some options:

- Buy a replacement part from the original manufacturer of the bed. If the originals failed prematurely, you may be entitled to free replacement parts. If not, at least you may be able to get the exact matching part for a relatively quick and easy repair.
- Take a photo of the old broken drawer slide and send it to a company that specializes in hardware, such as [Custom Service Hardware](http://cshardware.com) or [Woodworker's Hardware](http://wwhardware.com), for recommendations on replacement hardware.
- If you already know what you need, simply buy a [center-mount drawer slide](http://www.leevalley.com/us/wood/page.aspx?p=45056&cat=3,43614,43616&ap=2) of the appropriate style and size.
- Forego metal drawer slides altogether. Instead install UHMW plastic drawer runners, or wooden drawer runners with or without low-friction tape applied on the contact surfaces.

  - To prevent the drawer from tipping out, you can go a step further by using a [wooden sliding dovetailed drawer slide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001DT15YM).

Comment: +1 for UHMW Plastics. They make the absolutely best drawer guides.